# Dispatching requests to non thread-safe singleton object in Tokio

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I want to create a wrapper around an object from a third party library and then dispatch requests originating from TCP sockets to it via Tokio. Is there an idiomatic way to handle this in Tokio?

---

Conceptually, the interface looks like this:

```
impl MyObject {
    fn handle_requestA(&self, r: RequestA) -> ResponseA,
    fn handle_requestB(&self, r: RequestB) -> ResponseB,
    // ...
}
```

A couple of things to note:

1. the object is not thread-safe, so requests need to be serialized
2. request handlers may take a long time, so running them on the same thread as the rest of Tokio's event loop is probably not a good idea

I could just spin up a regular OS thread and feed it through a queue, but in that case I'd need to multiplex requests of different types onto it (and then demultiplex responses back to sockets). Is there some existing plumbing I could re-use?

A stretch-goal is to have a pool of `MyObject`s and load-balance requests between them.